# Enter key not submitting data in Firefox..Works fine in IE and Chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, firefox, onkeypress

```
Here's the code..

<div class="input-wrapper">
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
<input type="text" class="form-control message-input" ng-keypress="($event.charCode === 13) ? vm.addMessage($event) : null"
data-prod-idx="{{index}}" data-id="{{prod.ProductId}}"
ng-model="vm.models.msgText" ng-init="vm.models.msgText=''" placeholder="Type your message here...">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-submit col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1 message-send" ng-click="vm.addMessage($event)" data-prod-idx="{{index}}" data-id="{{prod.ProductId}}">Send</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to implement message chat box where user can send message. Clicking on button working everywhere but onkeypress doesn't work on Firefox only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charCode is deprecated. see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode).

[image]

Comment: Its not Working :(

Comment: @Mohit If you just want to detect the `Enter` key. replace `charCode` to `keyCode`.

Comment: Working Now... Thanks :)